# Detect build type (debug/release) in visual studio when using CMake

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, cmake, c++17, visual-studio-2019

I have a little game engine in which I need to define some custom macros when it is building in Debug or Release mode.

Here are a few lines of my CMake script which is supposed to do that:

```
if (CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE STREQUAL "Debug")
    set(OE_BUILD_TYPE_DEFINE "OE_DEBUG")
endif()
    
if (CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE STREQUAL "Release")
    set(OE_BUILD_TYPE_DEFINE "OE_RELEASE")
endif()

if (CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE STREQUAL "RelWithDebInfo")
    set(OE_BUILD_TYPE_DEFINE "OE_DEBUG")
endif()

if (CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE STREQUAL "MinSizeRel")
    set(OE_BUILD_TYPE_DEFINE "OE_RELEASE")
endif()

target_compile_definitions(OverEngine PRIVATE
    "_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS"
    "GLFW_INCLUDE_NONE"

    PUBLIC
    OE_BUILD_TYPE_DEFINE
)
```

It works great using `make` or `ninja` in Linux however on Windows using VisualStudio, the `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` variable is always empty. I know the reason. It is because VS can switch build type without re-running CMake unlike `make` or `ninja` generators.

Premake has something called `filter` which works just fine but for some other reason, I am not using it right now.

How do I set this up?

I am using VisualStudio 2019 16.7.2 and CMake 3.18.2 if it is needed.

EDIT:
fixed by replacing those lines with these lines:

```
target_compile_definitions(OverEngine PRIVATE
    "_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS"
    "GLFW_INCLUDE_NONE"

    PUBLIC
    $<$<CONFIG:Debug>:OE_DEBUG>
    $<$<CONFIG:Release>:OE_RELEASE>

    $<$<CONFIG:RelWithDebInfo>:OE_DEBUG>
    $<$<CONFIG:MinSizeRel>:OE_RELEASE>
)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You may want to use [generator expressions](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html?highlight=generator%20expression#variable-queries) here. They are evaluated at build time and therefore the build type is set even for multi-configuration generators as Visual Studio or Xcode.

```
target_compile_definitions(OverEngine
    PRIVATE
      _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
      GLFW_INCLUDE_NONE
    PUBLIC
      $<$<CONFIG:Debug>:OE_DEBUG>
      $<$<CONFIG:RelWithDebInfo>:OE_DEBUG>
      $<$<CONFIG:Release>:OE_RELEASE>
      $<$<CONFIG:MinSizeRel>:OE_RELEASE>
)
```

Comment: this code gave me this error: `$<CONFIG> expression requires one or zero parameters.` how ever using 4 generator expressions for each CONFIG, works for me.

Comment: My bad, I posted the code for CMake 3.19 which supports more than one variable in `$<CONFIG:cfgs>` generator expression. I'll edit the answer.

Answer (score -1):

> I have a little game engine in which I need to define some custom macros when it is building in Debug or Release mode.

### Do not use CMake functionality for this

I personally do not use a lot CMake generator expressions. The possible alternative in addition to CMake generator expression is performing this not via CMake, but directly from the MSVC compiler:

- First, you may want to detect that you're using the MSVC toolchain. It can be done by checking _MSC_VER macros (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/predefined-macros?view=msvc-170).
- Next you may want to use the following heuristic. When the source code is compiled with DEBUG version of C and C++ runtime via specifying for the compiler the flags `/MTd` `/MDd`  the `_DEBUG` macro is defined automatically by the compiler. You can use this heuristic to distinguish Debug builds and Release builds.

### References

1. [List of compiler options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/compiler-options-listed-alphabetically?view=msvc-170)
2. [About `_DEBUG` macro](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/debug?view=msvc-170)
3. [Toolchain-specific macro (mixed with standard C and C++ macroses) used by MSVC:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/predefined-macros?view=msvc-170)